# Is there a way to have some values divided into columns and other values not divided into the same columns in a single pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example:

| Date | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 23/07 | 50 |
| 23/07 | 45 |
| 23/07 | 51 |
| 23/07 | 52 |
| 23/07 | 44 |
| 23/07 | 49 |
| 23/07 | 51 |
| 23/07 | 54 |
| 23/07 | 48 |

My pivot table has "Date" in rows, "Number" in columns (which is also grouped) and "Count of Numbers" in values:

| Label | 0-49 | 50-99 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23/07 | 4 | 5 |

Then I added "Max. of Number" in values. This is what it looks like right now:

|  | 0-49 | 50-99 | 0-49 | 50-99 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Label | Count of Number | Count of Number | Max of Number | Max of Number |
| 23/07 | 4 | 5 | 49 | 54 |

What I want is for the "Max of Number" field to be outside the column separation, like this:

|  | 0-49 | 50-99 | Max of Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Label | Count of Number | Count of Number |  |
| 23/07 | 4 | 5 | 54 |

Since it doesn't make sense to have the "Max. of Number" limited by the grouped columns of "Number". Is that possible?

This is a really simple example that I just created for the question, but I have far more complex situations with the same problem, where I don't want one or more specific values to be divided in columns, while the rest of them need that separation.

PS: I know I can create 2 pivot tables, one with columns and one without. I'm just wandering if this is possible with a single pivot table.

Comment: I guess it's just not possible.